# Tensorflow - Any input gives me same output

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am facing a very strange problem where I am building an RNN model using tensorflow and then storing the model variables (all) using tf.Saver after I finish training.

During testing, I just build the inference part again and restore the variables to the graph. The restoration part does not give any error.

But when I start testing on the evaluation test, I always get same output from the inference all i.e. for all test inputs, I get the same output.

I printed the output during training and I do see that output is different for different training samples and cost is also decreasing.
But when I do testing, it always gives me same output no matter what is the input.

Can someone help me to understand why this could be happening? I want to post some minimal example but as I am not getting any error, I am not sure what should I post here. I will be happy to share more information if it can help the issue.

One difference I have between the inference graph during training and testing is the number of time steps in RNN. During training I train for n steps (n = 20 or more) for a batch before updating gradients while for testing  I just use one step as I only want to predict for that input.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to resolve this issue. This seemed to be happening as one of my input feature was very dominant in its original values due to which after some operations all values were converging to single number. 
Scaling that feature has helped to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem where different inputs are converging at the same output. I am not sure why though. Can you tell me what scaling do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a small reproducible case and post this as a bug to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues ? That will help this question get attention from the right people.